# Custom User Permissions without Roles c#

Tags: c#, permissions, authorization

I used ASP.Net Core 2 Identity default and built database like that 
User > Role > Permission.
Now, I want to build customize user permission **without role** with that database. Can I do that? Give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to implement authorization based on other rules than role belongings.